# Blazor specify the Href of a menu item to be a page in another project

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a Blazor server solution using

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref v6.0.0 and blazor mudblazor 6.10.0

. The solution has two projects ProjectA and ProjectB, ProjectA has all the Blazor scaffolding code and ProjectB has some additional Blazor pages and components which I want to use and reference from ProjectA.

ProjectA has a MudNavMenu in which it has a menu item which should point to a component in ProjectB it is defined as follows

```
<MudNavLink Href="/modelrange/model1"
```

Inside ProjectB there is a Razor Page inside the Folder structure Pages/ModelRange/index.razor

With a route definition as follows

```
@page "/modelrange/model1"
```

When I click on the link I get an error  stating that

> there's nothing at this address.

I have tried adding this to the startup.cs of ProjectA but with no luck

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load("ProjectB"));
```

Comment: What version on Blazor is this?

Comment: If you mean that ProjectA and ProjectB are literally in different .csproj files, then does that mean they are run as independent apps, with each having its own base URL?

Comment: yes ProjectA and ProjectB are in the same solution with different csproj files, projectA has all the blazor scaffolding but projectB contains some components

Comment: i am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref v6.0.0 and blazor mudblazor 6.10.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify your App.razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] {your target assembly}">
 .........
</Router>
```

Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-to-components-from-multiple-assemblies) realted

It's ok on myside:
[image]